# Vector from $SU(2)$ to $SO(3)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

I know how to change the element(a matrix) in $SU(2)$ to the matrix in $SO(3)$, and I found one way to change the state(vector) from $2\times 1$ to $3\times 1$, but I don't know why.
The method is showing below:
For any vector$|\psi\rangle \equiv (a+bi,c+di)^T$, with $\langle\psi|\sigma_x|\psi\rangle$ we can get the first line in (1), and with $\langle\psi|\sigma_y|\psi\rangle$ we can get the second line in (1), the same with the third line.

$$\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\begin{pmatrix} 
2(ac + bd) \\ 
2(-bc + ad)\\
a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
$\sigma $ above stands for Pauli operator, I think it's basic in quantum mechanics.
$$\sigma _x = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\sigma _y = \begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}, \sigma _z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
And for example, if the $2\times 1$ vector is $\begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta/2)\\sin(\theta /2)e^{i\phi}\end{pmatrix}$, the corresponding $3\times 1$ vector is exactly (using the (1) transformation)$\begin{pmatrix}sin(\theta)cos(\phi)\\sin(\theta)sin(\phi)\\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$
But I don't understand how to prove (1).

---

[***Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.SE***](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15463/55)

Comment: This is how the Bloch vector is defined.

Comment: No, the Bloch vector is defined as $e^{i\alpha}(cos(\theta /2)|0> + sin(\theta/2)e^{i\phi}|1>)$, but what I mentioned in the question has something to do with the $SU(2)$ group and $SO(3)$ group.

Comment: So to clarify question claims given an element of SU(2) and a vector it acts on given as (a+bi, c+di). There is a corresponding element of SU(3) which acts on the 3-element vector you gave above? Also what is $\sigma$?

Comment: $\sigma$ is the Pauli operator, I've amended the question above to make it more clear.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas The relation between$SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ is not bijection, it's a surjection, or 2 $SU(2)$ elements corresponding to 1 $SO(3)$ elements.

Comment: It's an equivalent (and more elegant) definition, as one can easily verify.

Comment: You mean it's a definition of Bloch vector?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch  I don't think so, you can calculate (1) equationin this way: with$|\psi\rangle\equiv(a+bi,c+di)^T$, and the first line of (1) is exactly $\langle\psi|\sigma_x|\psi\rangle$, the second line is exactly$\langle\psi|\sigma_y|\psi\rangle$, the third line is $\langle\psi|\sigma_z|\psi\rangle$. Definition should be basic instead of something you can  deduce.

Comment: It is unclear what your question is. Also, of course there can be equivalent definitions. It is a matter of taste which one you call the "definition".

Comment: I will amend it again, and to state it, I just don't understand why equation (1) can be deduced in the way I just shown.

Comment: Because it can be checked easily to be equivalent to the definition of the Bloch vector you give above?

Comment: I really don't think so... In this [book](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), paged 15, is the definition of Bloch vector.

Comment: Not only the Block vector (with bases $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ ), but also any two orthogonal bases can be transformed in this way, you can see from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0106071.pdf), the (11) equation.

Comment: Two points: (i) If A and B are equivalent, you can choose whether you call A and B the definition. It is a matter of taste. (That "your" definition is used for the Bloch vector is likely that it is more "pedestrian", coming from what people know, not that it is more elegant and natural from a higher-level perspective.) (ii) Your "definition" as $\langle \psi|\vec\sigma\|\psi\rangle$ is naturally rotationally invariant (due to the SU(2) <-> SU(3) mapping or the rotations) and thus works in any basis (and thus also more elegant).

Comment: **What is your question?** -- If it is *"But I don't understand how to prove (1)."*, this can be checked in two lines from the definition you give above for the Bloch vector!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly unorthodox, but fairly well motivated way to get this.

The Clifford algebra of $\mathbb R^3$, with $x^2=y^2=z^2=1$, is isomorphic to the algebra of $2\times2$ matrices over $\mathbb C$. You can take $$x = \sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\; y = \sigma_y = \begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix},\; z = \sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$ This algebra is isomorphic to the [biquaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biquaternion), the even part (terms $a+bzy+cxz+dyx$ with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$) is isomorphic to the quaternions, and the $SU(2)$ subgroup is the unit quaternions under the same isomorphism. Also, the matrix adjoint is the Clifford reversal (the operation of "writing the expression backwards"), which I'll therefore write using $\dagger$.

In any Clifford algebra, you can represent arbitrary rotations by even elements $R$ satisfying $RR^\dagger=1$. A rotation $R$ takes an arbitrary vector $v$ to $RvR^\dagger$ (which will always be a vector in the Clifford algebra). If you fix some arbitrary unit vector $v$, you can use it to define a quadratic mapping from the $SU(2)$ subgroup of the algebra to unit vectors in $\mathbb R^3$.

Now here is the weird part, which I think that no one entirely understands in the general case.

We are trying to define a quadratic function not on elements of the even Clifford algebra, but on column vectors. We can embed the column vectors into the algebra by adding a column of zeros, which doesn't change the left action of $SU(2)$. Note that $(1{+}z)/2 = \text{diag}(1,0)$, and therefore the column vectors, embedded in this way, are the image of the full algebra under right multiplication by $(1{+}z)/2$. (The choice of $z$ is not forced here: other embeddings of the column vectors are possible, corresponding to other unit vectors.)

Let's suppose that the column vector was a rotation "before" we hit it on the right with $(1{+}z)/2$. We want $RvR^\dagger$ for some $v$, but we don't have $R$, only $R(1{+}z)/2$. Note that $(R(1{+}z))^\dagger=(1{+}z)R^\dagger$ and $$R\frac{1{+}z}2 z \frac{1{+}z}2 R^\dagger = R\frac{1{+}z}2 R^\dagger = (RR^\dagger+RzR^\dagger)/2 = (1+RzR^\dagger)/2.$$

(The choice of $z$ as the reference vector is forced, given our earlier choice of projector: anything normal to it is projected to zero.)

We can therefore extract the rotated $\mathbb R^3$ vector corresponding to $\begin{pmatrix}a{+}bi\\c{+}di\end{pmatrix}$ by extracting the $σ_x,σ_y,σ_z$ components of $$2 \begin{pmatrix}a{+}bi&0\\c{+}di&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a{-}bi&c{-}di\\0&0\end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix} a^2+b^2 & (a{+}bi)(c{-}di) \\ (a{-}bi)(c{+}di) & c^2+d^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

and this is precisely your vector (1).

---

It's difficult to understand the meaning of the projector $(1{+}z)/2$. I don't think there is any other approach that makes the meaning any clearer, and I think that understanding the geometric meaning of these projectors in general (they exist for Clifford algebras of every dimension and signature) is an open problem.

Comment: I've also shown a way to calculate the (1) equation, that is: with $|\psi \rangle \equiv (a+bi, c+di)^T$, and the first line of (1) is exactly $\langle \psi| \sigma_x|\psi \rangle$, the second line is exactly $\langle \psi| \sigma_y |\psi\rangle$, the third line is $\langle \psi| \sigma_z |\psi\rangle$, I just don't know why this can be done.